# How to use Defining Query in SSDL in Entity Framework? Advantages and Examples will be helpful

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I need some info about using the Defining Query element within the SSDL of the Entity Framework.
Advantages of using it and scenarios where it would be helpful would really help.
An example and links will be great.

Answer (score 5):

I'm looking for the same information myself and I stumbled across this useful link:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/05/14/how-why-use-definingquery-element.aspx